# How do I expire by type in .htaccess for remote loaded Google fonts?

Tags: htaccess, headers, expires

Is it possible to set expire by type for remote fonts or Google analytics? I'm getting this report from GTMetrix and everything I've tried isn't working. Suggestions?

```
There are 4 static components without a far-future expiration date.
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&subset=latin,latin-ext
http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js
http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js
```

All of my other expires are working fine.  But apparently this type of thing isn't right?

```
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/font-woff "access 1 year"
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't change the expiry headers for remote files that aren't under your control.

The only way you could would be to host them on your own server - however you then remove the advantage of these files being hosted on powerful CDNs and the font files are probably already stored in other user's browser caches.

There are work-around methods to use [PHP classes to cache remote content by URL](http://surniaulula.com/2013/02/14/php-class-to-cache-remote-content-by-url/) that you might want to look into.

Comment: Thats pretty funny considering google's own pagespeed insights says to do the same thing.  You'd think it would compensate.

Comment: There's specific reasons for them not to set long cache times the analytic requests (otherwise they won't record visit data) - i'm not sure why they have short expiry set on fonts though.