# Add Expires headers in GTmetrix

Tags: seo, web-hosting, htaccess, page-speed, optimization

When I test the performance of my website via [GTmetrix.com](https://gtmetrix.com) it says that there are 2 **static components without a far-future expiration date.** and listed below links.

```
https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-49812165-2
https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js
```

So I have asked about this before in [past question about GTmextrix](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/124417/how-do-i-add-the-an-expires-header-for-external-url-components-as-suggested-by-g) .

So what I wants to know is that **is it OK these `js` files to be saved in my server and then cached them via `.htaccess` and also if its OK could anyone please tell me for how many days I can cache these files.**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it OK these js files to be saved in my server

Sure. You must only seriously **care about updates**. Google doesn't recommend to host such files locally - the only cause for it is that the most users hosting such files locally don't do updates in the timely manner.

Comment: It may be "OK" to copy these files to your server, but whether you really should or not is another matter. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/124627/1243

Comment: If anyone interested about this here the best answer I found https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/124417/how-do-i-add-the-an-expires-header-for-external-url-components-as-suggested-by-g